# Windows 10 CMD responds extremely slow

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, command-line, performance

My command line is so slow. I mean even `ruby -v` takes 10-13 seconds to return version and more complex commands like running `rails s` is a pain.

1. I tried chkdsk and no problem found.
2. Tried to have more empty hard-drive space (got 400 GB now) and didn't worked.
3. Installed cmder and nothing changed.
4. Installed antivirus and nothing found.
5. Updated windows and not resolved also.

Here is my system specs;

> i5-4210M Cpu (2c4t 2,6GHz/3,2GHz)
>
> 12 GB ram
>
> 500 GB free hard-disk space
>
> Windows 10 Home-64 bit version.

This is the screenshot of task manager.

--NEW

[image: https://imgur.com/a/B8UY0sx]

[image: https://imgur.com/oTLlERT]

This is SMART results using Speccy

[image: https://imgur.com/a/qnBNRw8]

This is from the resources monitor.

1- https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLsdw.jpg
2- https://i.stack.imgur.com/81vgK.jpg

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87049/discussion-on-question-by-user972462-windows-10-cmd-responds-extremely-slow).

Comment: I have a similar problem. The cmd `C:\Windows:mode con:rate=31 delay=0`, that I use to cure a slow character repeat problem that occurs every now and then, takes 2 whole seconds to run. With Win 7, I could hardly see the cmd window. It was gone again in a split second.